# T-SQL Convert Oracle BITAND to SQL with two fields

Tags: oracle, t-sql

I trying to translate convert an Oracle **bitand** statement to a T-SQL statement. Oracle uses the statement:

```
BITAND(FIELD1, FIELD2)
```

Comment: [& (Bitwise AND)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace BITAND(FIELD1, FIELD2) with
(FIELD1 & FIELD2)